# how to find multiple testcases are pass or failed in unit testing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, tdd

How to find test-cases are passed or failed if we run multiple test-case in a single `TestMethod()` in unit test using Visual Studio 2010.i need to find which one was pass and which one got failed.
Ex: In XML i am having 2 test-cases like

```
<Testcases>
  <Test id="1">
      <Employee>A</Employee>
      <Country>B</Country>
  </Test>
</Testcases>
<Testcases>
  <Test id="2">
      <Employee>C</Employee>
      <Country>D</Country>
  </Test>
</Testcases>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mix test cases in a single method. Each test case should get its own method. This way each test case gets a clear name and your code gets easier to find, read and understand.

Comment: in my xml i having 2 testcases with same type of input data in that case .so i cannot write different methods for each test cases.what could be the best solution for this

Comment: Create multiple test methods and extract duplicate logic into a helper method.

Comment: nice answer steven :)

Answer (score 0):

Steven is right, but there isn't always possibility to do that, for example if the boss tells you to do it and not asking what do you think. in those cases the test-case should return a number indicate in what case he failed

Comment: If your boss is managing you add this level of detail, their are some serious trust issues or he is not suited for a job as boss. But neitherway, no matter what your boss says, that doesn't make it good practice.

Comment: i agree, @Steven, but not always i will get good bosses... anyway +1 for the excellent answer

Comment: If your boss is that bad, you might want to switch jobs. No fun working with stinky bosses.

Comment: @Steven not always an option :) and sometimes it pays enough to stay

Comment: Fine by me, but don't use 'the boss tells me' as an argument for doing things wrong. Stand by your profession. You know what's best. For you and your boss. Besides, you can answer all questions on stackoverflow with 'if your boss tells you', but that doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes agree with stevern .. each unit test case method should have only one case to test ...
Consider a simple method to test if any int is positive or negative

Then test cases should have different name for positive, negative and zero values for testing ...
So from name only we can identify weather test cases are passed or failed

This is a single responsibility one method or one entity should have only one reason to change the same ....